# Edge flicker when transitioning between screens ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, flicker

After upgrading to xcode 5, I notice there is a flicker on the edge of the screen when transitioning between two screen. The flicker shows up as a vertical white line on the edge of the frame. This only appears to be happening on ios7.

The transition that I have between the two screens is via a storyboard segue.

UPDATE:

I fixed the issue by adding:
self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
to my views.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I had to set `clipsToBounds` to `YES` on my views. This fixes the problem.

Comment: I would give +1000 to this. Basically I have complex graphics in my iOS app and started to get some flickering around my UITableViewCell when I have opened a semi transparent view on top of my view... Did not know where to start the search... That has fixed the issue... :) THANK YOU.

Comment: Should I need to do to all my subviews ? Please reply

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes in iOS7 when you try to update UI from background. So as to avoid above, you should update UI using `GCD` Method as shown below.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      // Update UI (e.g. Alert, label changes etc)
});
```

or

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      // Update UI (e.g. Alert, label changes etc)
});
```

This will make sure to update in main queue.

Comment: view_did_load is called in the main thread correct? So for label changes made in there I can leave them as is? I tried putting the entire viewWillAppear function inside dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue), and the issue is still persisting. Also I cannot reproduce on the simulator -- is there a way to easily repro on simulator so it's easier for me to test?

Comment: You should create method for code in viewWillAppear and call that method. You should not call viewWillAppear directly.

Comment: Yeah I will do that to make it cleaner after...however, that shouldn't result in different behavior correct?

Comment: Where should I put the dispatch_async? Inside the newly defined function, or inside viewWillAppear, around the function call? Do you know if I can reproduce on the simulator?

Comment: I tried this, and I still see the issue persisting.

Comment: I figured out the issue. I had to set clipsToBounds to YES on my views. This fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with tableView Segues in iOS7 and the clipsToBounds BOOL did nothing for me.  The fix for me was by loading my background image in viewDidAppear as opposed to viewDidLoad.  example below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First", @"Second", @"Third", nil];
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 0, 0);
    self.tableView.contentInset = inset;

//Don't load your background image or color here
}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [[AppDelegate sharedInstance] setNavTitle:@"Title"];

//load your background image here

    self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage     imageNamed:@"FirstViewBackground"]];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved the issue in my situation.

I had some custom UIView inside Container View. Container View had Background Color (probably I accidentally did this) set to White color. And between transitions I saw white line flickering (sometimes, randomly). When I set Container's View colour to Default, flickering on transitions disappeared.