# viewController edge (sometimes) flickers with white line with animated transition in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a native iOS app written in objective-C (Xcode5) that shows a weird artifact on the top-left border of a subview during a standard animated transition. This artifact consists of a flickering white line that lasts very shortly (less than a second, but can still be clearly noticed) and that does not occurr always (more or less 3 times on 10, when pushing exactly the same button).
Here is an example of how it looks like:

[image]

I could see this artifact with 4 different devices (iPhone 5S, 5, 4 and iPad Mini) with iOS 7.1 installed. I tried also to close all the apps in background and restart the devices, but the artifact is still there.

I tried by setting [`clipsToBounds` to `YES` as suggested in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22295882/1709835), but it didn't work for me.

Could this be a bug of iOS7? The white flickering line doesn't appear sistematically on every transition, but just sometimes. In the app I'm simply calling a `pushViewController` `animated:YES`, therefore the transition is completely handled by iOS.

Any suggestion or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement the animation on main thread, this may solve the problem.